# Android Performance Tuner (or Tuner Fork) with React Native App

Tags: android, react-native, performance, google-play-console

I may have missed a big point here, but I can't find anything that refers to Android Performance Tuner (also known as Tuning Fork) and React Native Apps.

In fact, I want the Android Vitals menu to be full of data, and the Google documentation only mentions Android Performance Tuner to generate data. How do I get Android Performance Tuner to work with React Native? Is this only related to game apps? Can I use another library to get this data?

Comment: Unless someone has ported that library to react-native, you'll have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is not just for games - suppose to work for apps too although I'm not sure if it has any use. There isn't a React-Native package to setup. You need to add native code to the main app file at start up inside the `onCreate()` method and enable the service via google cloud. You'll be familiar with the flow of adding native code if you've added a splash screen.

The docs are hard to find but it is here:

https://developer.android.com/games/sdk/performance-tuner/custom-engine

Comment: i want to implement APT in my app(non game an no c and c++ involved ) , no blogs or  tutorials to integrate in app ...can u please explain how to do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75031804/how-to-integrate-android-performance-tuner-in-non-game-applications