# How to integrate Android performance tuner in non game applications?

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-games

I want to integrate Android Performance Tuner(APT) in my android application.
I don't have any C and C++ code in my app, completely Kotlin and android code.

Does APT supports non gaming apps?

i came through two code labs

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-performance-tuner-native#0

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-performance-tuner-unity#0

But these are purely game bases applications.

How do i integrate APT in non games android application which not uses C and C++ ?

Do we have any alternative other than APT ?

Comment: I'm having the same concern. Did you come to a conclusion?

Comment: @ZahraJamshidi Unfortunately no